# Import via relative path global variables module

Tags: python, global-variables, python-import, relative-path

Here is my directory structure:

```
 .
`-- parent
    |-- child
    |   |-- globalvar.py
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- subchild
    |       |-- __init__.py
    |       `-- module.py
    `-- main.py
```

The globalvar.py in the child directory consist of the global variables that I would like to use in my application:

**globalvar.py**

```
def variables():
        global event_id

        event_id = 2100
```

In main.py, I'm calling the globalvar.py via import to initialize (child.globalvar.variables):

**main.py**

```
import child.globalvar
from child.subchild.module import display

child.globalvar.variables()

display()
```

Here is what I in my module.py file under the directory subchild:

```
from ..globalvar import variables

def display():

        print globalvar.event_id
```

This is the traceback I get when I execute main.py:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    display()
  File "/parent/child/subchild/module.py", line 5, in display
    print globalvar.event_id
NameError: global name 'globalvar' is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing the import statement in my module.py file:

**BEFORE:**

```
from ..globalvar import variables
```

**AFTER:**

```
from .. import globalvar
```